# ssh: tunnel through remote server to another server

Tags: ssh

I have ssh access to my work network using user `remote` on port 4000:

```
ssh remote@123.123.123.123 -p 4000
```

Authentication is done using ssh keys

However, I am currently in China, and the connection is very flaky.

We have a cloud server sitting in Hong Kong which we can tunnel through though, giving a more stable connection

I can login as user `foo` with the associated password.

```
ssh foo@100.100.100.100
```

How can I put the 2 together so that I can open an interactive shell session via ssh from my local machine to `123.123.123.123:4000` as user `remote` via `100.100.100.100:22` as user `foo`?

**Edit:**

*I am unable to comment on the below answer because Javascript has been blocked here in China, and comments use Javascript.*

A direct tunnel doesn't work because authentication is done with my ssh keys.

When I start an ssh session to `remote@123.123.123.123` from `foo@100.100.100.100` authentication fails

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I somehow need my ssh session to look like it is coming from my localhost, with my ssh keys, but to be tunnelled via `foo@100.100.100.100`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to put them together like this

```
ssh -t foo@100.100.100.100 ssh remote@123.123.123.123 -p 4000
```

since the ssh command allows you to specify a command to run on the remote server.

EDIT:

If you only have your ssh keys locally (the keys for `123.123.123.123` aren't on the cloud server), you should be able to add `-A` to forward the authentication, so the command will be

```
ssh -At foo@100.100.100.100 ssh remote@123.123.123.123 -p 4000
```

Note that for this to work, you need to have `ssh-agent` running locally, and your key must be registered using `ssh-add` (you can use `ssh-add -L` to check if your key is available to the ssh agent).